# How can I create a graph with time variation of all the polygons in a Shapefile in GEE?

Tags: time-series, google-earth-engine, sentinel1

I have a problem. I would like to get a time series graph with the mean of each of the polygons in my shapefile (data_shp) using GEE. But I can only get a single mean for all the polygons.

I tried changing the "regions:" but it doesn't good.

Thanks for help me!

I add the code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fbryanalemancr%2FScritp_Elevation%3APrueba